PhpStorm: removed unused element warning if specific attributes are present
I'm currently working on a Symfony-based CMS which uses attributes to declare callbacks. Because of that the function is not called directly anywhere in the code. This causes PhpStorm to show a "Unused element" warning despite the function is used.
Example:
#[AsCallback(table: 'name_of_table', target: 'callback_trigger')]
public function listEntries(array $row): string  // PhpStorm Warning: "Unused element: 'listEntries'"
{
    ...
}

Is there any option to supress the "Unused element" warning if this specific attribute is present?
I tried searching in the PhpStorm settings but couldn't find anything fitting my need. There seems to be a setting to suppress the warning based on annotations but not attributes.

I think if you add
#[\PhpStorm\Suppress('UnusedElement')]

the problem will be fixed please try to change the code to
#[AsCallback(table: 'name_of_table', target: 'callback_trigger')]
// PhpStorm specific suppression
#[\PhpStorm\Suppress('UnusedElement')]
public function listEntries(array $row): string  // No more warning here
{
    ...
}

